# Box shadow for css generated arrow

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm using the following code for creating **up** arrow in css:

```
border-bottom: 10px solid red;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent
```

I also want to apply a `box-shadow` only to the arrow not the rectangular box around it ([FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j6qsekcc/1/)). Is it possible this way?

**NOTE:-** I don't want to use any image, it should be with CSS.

Comment: As far as i'm aware the only way to do this would be to create 3 seperate `<div>`'s all 1px wide and apply the box-shadow to them but i still don't think it would be that neat of an shadow

Comment: Take a look at this: http://dabblet.com/gist/1592060

Comment: Thanks guys, even both the answers are correct, I have to select one. :-(

Comment: @Abhi I've added some more alternatives for you to choose from. More choice for what is best on your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, using the `border` hack doesn't work when using `box-shadow`.

### CSS

Instead, you will want to use css `transform` to rotate an element and hide the `overflow`. You will need to use a pseudo-element.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

### Canvas

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('triangle');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(25, 10);
context.lineTo(40, 40);
context.lineTo(10, 40);
context.lineTo(25, 10);

context.closePath();
context.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)";
context.shadowBlur = 7;
context.shadowOffsetX = 2;
context.shadowOffsetY = 5;
context.fillStyle = "rgba(132, 28, 255, 0.8)";
context.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="triangle" height="50" width="50">Triangle</canvas>
```

### SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="svg-triangle" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" />
    <!-- stdDeviation is how much to blur -->
    <feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur" />
    <!-- how much to offset -->
    <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode/>
      <!-- this contains the offset blurred image -->
      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to -->
    </feMerge>
  </filter>
  <polygon points="50,10 90,90 10,90" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the choices. The first choice(CSS) suffice my need.

Answer (score 6):

**A Single-Property CSS-Only Solution**

The `box-shadow` property may not work with the border-triangle-hack, but there's still a single-property solution: the drop-shadow filter.

```
.shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px #000);
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px #000);
  /* webkit browsers still need the vendor prefix */
}
```

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter):

> Applies a drop shadow effect to the input image. **A drop shadow is effectively a blurred, offset version of the input image's alpha mask drawn in a particular color, composited below the image.** The function accepts a parameter of type `<shadow>` (defined in CSS3 Backgrounds), with the exception that the `inset` keyword is not allowed. This function is similar to the more established `box-shadow` property; the difference is that with filters, some browsers provide hardware acceleration for better performance.

The arguments to the `drop-shadow` filter are formatted identically to the values of the `box-shadow` property (although it cannot make inset shadows). [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) has a great article describing CSS filters.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) is decent, but webkit browsers still (as of the time of writing) need the vendor prefix. Currently, these two lines will cover about 75% of users worldwide.

Below is a slightly more robust solution that is still CSS-only, but *should* work in IE5.5+, FF31+, and webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc.) bringing your user coverage very close to 100%.

```css
.triangle {
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.shadow {
  /* inline svg-filter-fix for Firefox 31 - 33 */
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height="0" width="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="drop-shadow"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.2"/><feOffset dx="0" dy="0" result="offsetblur"/><feFlood flood-color="#000"/><feComposite in2="offsetblur" operator="in"/><feMerge><feMergeNode/><feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/></feMerge></filter></svg>#drop-shadow');
  /* standard syntax, currently only supported by Firefox 34+ */
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #000);
  /* webkit syntax, currently supports about 66% of browsers */
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #000);
  /* syntax for IE5.5 - IE7 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=1, offX=0px, offY=0px, Color='#000000');
  /* syntax for IE8+ */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=1, offX=0px, offY=0px, Color='#000000')";
}
```

```html
<span class="triangle shadow"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This Way

```
    .triangle-with-shadow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 10px -17px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Prefixes... */
  top: 75px;
  left: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 10px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j6qsekcc/2/)